# making an image link from a db asp.net mvc 4

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-4, hyperlink

I have this foreach loop pulling images from my db :

```
     `@foreach (var item in model)
     <tr>
     <td>
     <img width="50" height="50" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Product", new { item.ProductId})"/>
     </td>
     ...`
```

I tried to wrap it in an 'a' tag but all I get is 404's.

```
    <a href = "~/..."> <img width="".../></a>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your image displaying correctly? What is the URL that is getting 404?

Comment: the image is fine but when I click on the image, no matter the url I choose, I get a 404

Comment: What is the URL that it is attempting?

Comment: `<a href="~/Views/Shared/_index"><img...></a>` . I've tried other views but can't seem to get it to display.

Comment: Try `<a href="@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")"><img /></a>`

Comment: "the image is fine but when I click on the image, no matter the url I choose, I get a 404" - so what is it that you are trying to achieve? Just to show an image whose location is based from a model? Or show an image with a hyperlink - and both urls will come from a model?

Comment: @vonv. an image with a hyperlink is what I'm trying to achieve. You click the image and you're taken to the edit page.

Answer (score 1):

> an image with a hyperlink is what I'm trying to achieve. You click the
>   image and you're taken to the edit page.

Okay so suppose you get the image as shown in your question `Product.GetImage` and then the edit page is called by `Product.Edit`, you can have this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Edit")"><img src="@Url.Action("GetImage","Product")" /></a>
```